# Update thermostat result from api every 10 seconds in a C# console application

Tags: c#, json, api, console-application

I need help on updating thermostat temperature from thingspeak.io API on every 10 seconds. I get JSON data from thingspeak channel and i convert it and display it in console.

**This is my code so far**

```
string url = "http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/135/feed.json";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
var data = webClient.DownloadString(url);
dynamic feed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data);
List<dynamic> feeds = feed.feeds.ToObject<List<dynamic>>();
string field1 = feeds.Last().field1;
float temperature = float.Parse(field1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine("----------CURRENT CHANNEL----------");
Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine("Channel name: " + feed.channel.name);
Console.WriteLine("Temperature: " + temperature.ToString() + " °C");
Console.WriteLine("\n");

int trenutna_temp = Convert.ToInt32(temperature);

Console.WriteLine("----------DEVICES----------");

if (trenutna_temp < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("turn on heating);
}
else if (trenutna_temp > 10 && trenutna_temp < 20)
{
    Console.WriteLine("turn off");
}
else if (trenutna_temp > 20)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Turn on cooling");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Now I'd like to update this data on every 10 seconds. I would really appreciate if any of you guys could point me in right direction or help me fix the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use System.Threading.Timer:

```
public static void Main() 
{  
   System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(UpdateThermostat, 5, 0, 2000); //10 times 1000 miliseconds
   Console.ReadLine();
   t.Dispose(); // dispose the timer
}


private static void UpdateThermostat(Object state) 
{ 
   // your code to get your thermostat
   //option one to print on the same line:
   //move the cursor to the beginning of the line before printing:
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now);

   //option two to print on the same line:
   //printing "\r" moves cursor back to the beginning of the line so it's a trick:
    Console.Write("\r{0}",DateTime.Now);
}
```

[Timer MSDN documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: hmm. doesn't seem to be working, or am i doing something wrong :S

Comment: you need some way to delay the main thread so the app doesn't stop executing.  Such as Console.ReadLine();  Run the code above, it should demonstrate.

Comment: thats it! this works. tho it triggers that it keeps repeating and displaying it under already displayed status (like this : http://s15.postimg.org/43vmgn263/Capture.jpg ) . is it any possible way to refresh already displayed status?

Comment: Cannot say I can live up to that :-)  but you're most welcome!